# gitlab API PUT(projects/:id) 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: gitlab, http-status-code-405

I want rename the gitlab project path.
So I use the gitlab api PUT(projects/:id).
but http error 405 method not allowed.
I don't know that.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

In the projects/:id section, make sure you're replacing ':id' with the actual id that you want (e.g. projects/123).

It should end up generating a URI for the PUT that looks something like:

https://gitlab.mydomain.com/api/v3/projects/123?id=123&path=MyProject